# How to create self signed SSL certificate for test purposes?

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

How to easily create self signed SSL certificate for testing purposes?

Comment: Please use the search, this should have been asked and answered already, if not search the other stackoverflow Q&A sites, too please // close-votes but nobody suggested a duplicate - there ain't one?

Answer (score 127):

You can do this via openssl:

1. Install openssl package (if you are using Windows, download binaries [here](https://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html)).
2. Generate private key: `openssl genrsa 2048 > private.pem`
3. Generate the self signed certificate: `openssl req -x509 -days 1000 -new -key private.pem -out public.pem`
4. If needed, create PFX: `openssl pkcs12 -export -in public.pem -inkey private.pem -out mycert.pfx`

Comment: As a one-liner: openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -out server.crt -keyout server.key

Comment: Must add -sha256 to avoid more errors

Comment: The link to the Windows binaries above doesn't work anymore. Openssl.org does not provide any binaries themselves but the do offer a list to binaries in their [wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries).

Comment: You can download cygwin for openssl for windows and check openssl from tools.

Comment: 5. `openssl pkcs12 -in mycert.pfx -out mycert.pem -nodes` to create mycert.pem certificate (for example needed by jupyter) from .pfx,
as according to [this document.](http://webhelp.evisions.com/HelpFiles/MAPS/en/Content/OpenSSL%20Certificates.htm)

Comment: For Windows users:  **Git Bash** includes `openssl`. *I thick Git is one of must have things in developer's system* ^)

Comment: For windows, you could find it at "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\openssl.exe"

Comment: On Win10 I was running this from git bash -- Generating public works.  Attempting to generate pfx seemed to hang.  It's related to git bash problem when getting password -- the fix is to prefix openssl command with $ winpty openssl...  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156938/openssl-hangs-during-pkcs12-export-with-loading-screen-into-random-state for more info.

Comment: If the `openssl` command hangs, try do `winpty openssl ...`.

Comment: On my local development machine with Windows and Visual Studio I use the IIS Express Development Certificate for deployment tests on IIS

Comment: If you encounter encoding errors, use: ```openssl genrsa -out private.pem 2048``` instead of the first command.