# How can I provide a SSL certificate with create-react-app?

Tags: node.js, facebook, reactjs, ssl, https

I am trying to host a react app I created and tested locally using the facebook boilerplate. 
The client app interacts with an API I made using node.js, and with which I had no issue setting up a secure connection (with a node.js client sending my SSL certificate, for testing). 
However, I am encountering difficulties when it comes to using react to send my SSL certificate instead of a self-signed one which causes me to encounter this error using chrome and trying to access to https://example.net:3000 :

> Your connection is not private (NET:ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID)

The documentation did not quite help me:

> Note that the server will use a self-signed certificate, so your web browser will almost definitely display a warning upon accessing the page.
>   https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#using-https-in-development

How can I use my own SSL certificate (which I already use on another app on my domain and works like a charm) instead of this self-signed one ? Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I was able to get a local certificate working **without** modifying the `webpack-dev-server` files using `react-scripts` `3.4.1` (technically added in `3.4.0` but I had some—probably unrelated—issues). I added these two environment variables to my `.env.development`:

```
SSL_CRT_FILE=.cert/server.crt
SSL_KEY_FILE=.cert/server.key
```

Notes:

- `.cert` is a folder I created in the root of my project
- [My script that generates the SSL certificate](https://gist.github.com/ptvandi/5a33c28d74ccc5100d7fe2bf5de96deb)
- [Official documentation on these two environment variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-https-in-development/#custom-ssl-certificate)

Comment: Is the certificate generated by your script self signed or signed by a certificate authority?

Comment: It's self-signed.

Comment: The script doesn't work, it gets stucked on almost every openssl command (using windows 10)

Comment: if it gets stuck on openssl (generate rootCA.key), modify the script by add 'winpty' before any 'oppenssl' command. Found answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156938/openssl-hangs-during-pkcs12-export-with-loading-screen-into-random-state

Comment: @viethieule is there any workaround for this for Ubuntu?

Comment: If the certificate is self-signed why do you need these steps instead of just adding https=true to your.env

Answer (score 35):

Update: see Andi's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60821222/138585) below. 
In recent version you should set environment variable to configure the certificate

```
SSL_CRT_FILE=.cert/server.crt
SSL_KEY_FILE=.cert/server.key
```

---

Ejecting `create-react-app` is not recommended since you won't be able to seamlessly upgrade it. Moreover, you can easily have valid SSL certificate without ejecting. 
You will need to copy your certificate to `node_modules/webpack-dev-server/ssl/server.pem`. The downside is that you need to manually copy the file. However, one way to make this seamless is to add a `postinstall` script that creates a symlink. 
Here is a [script](https://gist.github.com/eladmoshe/0ca3f60952a7c4c24ab9aa028e0873bf) I created:

```
#!/bin/bash
# With create-react-app, a self signed (therefore invalid) certificate is generated.
# 1. Create some folder in the root of your project
# 2. Copy your valid development certificate to this folder
# 3. Copy this file to the same folder
# 4. In you package.json, under `scripts`, add `postinstall` script that runs this file.
# Every time a user runs npm install this script will make sure to copy the certificate to the 
# correct location

TARGET_LOCATION="./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/ssl/server.pem"
SOURCE_LOCATION=$(pwd)/$(dirname "./local-certificate/server.pem")/server.pem

echo Linking ${TARGET_LOCATION} TO ${SOURCE_LOCATION}
rm -f ${TARGET_LOCATION} || true
ln -s ${SOURCE_LOCATION} ${TARGET_LOCATION}
chmod 400 ${TARGET_LOCATION} # after 30 days create-react-app tries to generate a new certificate and overwrites the existing one. 
echo "Created server.pem symlink"
```

Your `package.json` should look something like:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "postinstall": "sh ./scripts/link-certificate.sh"
}
```

- My solution is based on this [thread](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1411#issuecomment-347668164)

Comment: If I understand this correctly, one would move the three files to the `node_modules/webpack-dev-server/ssl/` dir and then execute `npm run build && serve -s build`. OR, `npm run postinstall && npm run build && serve -s build` ... is that correct?

Comment: Not exactly. You should create a folder in the root of your app (i.e. sibling of `node_modules`) that contains your `server.pem` and the script file. Then you add the `postinstall` script to your `package.json`. The script then runs automatically after each `npm install`, so no need to change your workflow. HTH.

Comment: Should I add `./local-certificate` to `.gitignore`?

Comment: You usually don't want to commit certificates to Git, so yes.

Comment: Two things I had to work through. My server certificate is from Let's Encrypt and the private key is in a separate file. I had to add it to `fullchain.pem` and then rename it to `server.pem`. Also, because my dev user isn't root, I had to make sure my user is the owner/group of the new `server.pem`.

Comment: [As of `react-scripts@3.4.0`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#nail_care-enhancement-1) as stated in Andi's answer, the certificate can be provided via environment variable which is a modern, elegant and OS-independent approach as opposed to the proposed bash script workaround above. Because this is a highly upvoted and also the accepted answer, I believe it should be updated, at least stating that there is an out-of-the-box solution to the task for modern versions of React.

Comment: Where do you add the certificate chain so that your certificate can be recognized by all browsers?

Answer (score 17):

To expand on Elad's answer:

- 1. Create a self-signed certificate following the instructions linked to from https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/tree/master/examples/cli/https
- 2. Save the pem file (containing both the certificate and private key) somewhere in your project (e.g. `/cert/server.pem`)
- 3. Modify your package.json scripts:

     ```
     "start": "HTTPS=true react-scripts start",
     "prestart": "rm ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/ssl/server.pem && cp -f ./cert/server.pem ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/ssl",
     ```

Comment: I ended up using devcert-cli (I just saw mkcert today which also looks good) to generate a signed certificate for localhost in `./cert`. I then add the following `prestart` script to my package.json: `cp -f ./cert/server.pem ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/ssl`. The benefit of using devcert is that you get a signed certificate vs. self-signed and so you won't see any warning or errors in Chrome.

Comment: What happens if we also need to add a key and a passphrase?

Comment: Note the key to step #2 above is to concatenate the certificate and private key into a single file.  In the case of a LetsEncrypt certificate we made, that's privkey.pem + fullchain.pem.

Comment: If I have a cert.pem and key.pem, how do I create the server.pem?

Comment: If the certificate is self-signed why do you need these steps instead of just adding https=true to your.env?

Answer (score 9):

Your server that serves files from that port needs to be configured to use your SSL cert. I'm guessing you are using webpack-dev-server on that port (that's what `npm start` does in create-react-app), and maybe a different server (apache, nginx, etc) on port 80?

You can either serve your compiled files using your already configured server, or configure webpack-dev-server to use your SSL cert.

To do this, you can use webpack-dev-server's `--cert` option. See https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html

> NOTE: you need an extra `--` to pass arguments through npm run to the underlying command, e.g. `npm start -- --cert ...`.

If you want to do this using npm start, which calls a custom start script, you'll have to edit that start script. You may need to use the `eject` command first, which dumps all the config code into your repo so you can change it.

Here is the source code of the start script: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/scripts/start.js#L230

I should also note that webpack-dev-server isn't intended to be used in a production environment.

Have fun!

Comment: Life saver! Thank you so much.
I configured webpack-dev-server after running eject and it works perfect.

Comment: @MontasarJarraya maybe you can post your own solution step by step for beginners?

Comment: Please note that you do not absolutely need to eject in order to do this, if you use `react-app-rewired`—see https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired. I found that to get this to work I still needed to set the environment variable HTTPS to `true`

Comment: That's awesome, @NatKuhn. I wasn't aware of that option.

Comment: I can't get the `--cert` option working with `npm start`. Are the command-line arguments not passed through or something?

Comment: @anddero you need an extra -- to pass arguments through npm run to the underlying command. `npm start -- --cert`

Comment: Where do you add the certificate chain so that your certificate can be recognized by all browsers?

Comment: @Maf You could use, for example, mkcert, which handles installing the generated cert into the local system trust store. https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert

Comment: @AlexK, yes you could. Now what about configuring real certificates trusted everywhere?

Comment: @Maf You would buy one or use a service like Let's Encrypt and install it in your web server. Create react app has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Yes, neither with mkcert.

Comment: You can do the same thing with a real cert. I gave some ideas above for how to get one. You shouldn't be using webpack-dev-server in production though so there's not really a good reason to use a real cert. The advantage of creating your own cert instead of using the built-in one is you can install it locally so all of your browsers accept it as a trusted cert,  which is what you asked.

Answer (score 7):

Ultimately, this is what helped me. on Windows.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set HTTPS=true&&set SSL_CRT_FILE=./.cert/cert.pem&&set SSL_KEY_FILE=./cert/key.pem&&react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

But first, i got the certificates like this.

```
//create a certficate folder
mkdir -p .cert
//create the actual certificates in the folder 
mkcert -key-file ./.cert/key.pem -cert-file ./.cert/cert.pem "localhost"
```

note : i had to install mkcert using chocolatey, on windows. So, you probably have to start with this, before getting the React js app to work with https on windows.

Update1 : I put the entire code on github, if someone wants to see a full solution in action. link here - https://github.com/Jay-study-nildana/FrontEndForStudents/tree/main/ReactJSForStudents/httpshelloworld

Comment: A dot is missing in the start script SSL_KEY_FILE path before the word cert. Correct: SSL_KEY_FILE=./.cert/key.pem

Comment: This worked beautifully for localhost. Do you know how to get it working with the remote network IP? I tried this but although the keys are being generated, Chrome is displaying it as unsecure: `mkcert -key-file ./remotework/key.pem -cert-file ./remotework/cert.pem "http://192.168.20.115"`

Comment: my friend, i am only a beginner students coding tutor. so, the basics is all i know.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the webpack config of react-scripts when using `HTTPS=true` along side `SSL_CRT_FILE` & `SSL_CRT_FILE`. So you should just be able to add it to the env to set the paths to your cert.

[image: https config in react-scripts]

Comment: Where do you add the certificate chain so that your certificate can be recognized by all browsers?

Answer (score 3):

Are we looking for integration of SSL (HTTPS) to localhost for application? Or securely API call with any encryption (specific) algo.

If SSL enablement only,

1. Need to change at package.json file with HTTPS like –

   ```
   "scripts": {
       "start": "HTTPS=true react-scripts start",
       "build": "react-scripts build",
       "test": "react-scripts test",
       "eject": "react-scripts eject"
   },
   ```
2. Create your SSL certificate
3. In the project root folder, run:

   ```
   openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout keytmp.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
   ```
4. run the

   ```
   openssl rsa -in keytmp.pem -out key.pem
   mkdir .cert
   mv key.pem .cert/key.pem
   mv cert.pem .cert/cert.pem
   ```
5. Enable your certificate (.perm) like –

   ```
   "scripts": {
       "start": "HTTPS=true SSL_CRT_FILE='./.cert/cert.pem' SSL_KEY_FILE='./.cert/key.pem' react-scripts start",
       "build": "react-scripts build",
       "test": "react-scripts test",
       "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
   ```
6. now run with https://lochost:3000

Comment: Why all these steps for a self-signed certificate?

Comment: This one solved it for me, specifically the `"start": "HTTPS=true SSL_CRT_FILE='./.cert/cert.pem' SSL_KEY_FILE='./.cert/key.pem' react-scripts start"` line

Answer (score 2):

Do not use self-signed certificates as I saw in some answers. There are lots of trusted certificate providers over the web. You just need to have a valid domain and you can easily prove that you are the owner. My certificate was provided by this authority for free: https://www.noip.com/.

1. Create your `private key` and the `Certificate Signing Request` (`CSR`):

   `openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout your_domain.key -out your_domain.csr`
2. Go to a certificate provider like `noip` and request a certificate by submitting your `CSR` and you'll receive at your email a trusted signed cerificate. Don't forget to `keep secret your private key`, just share the CRS with your authority!
3. Then in react you just need to have your `.env` file configured as follows (`.cert/` folder in the root directory):

   `HOST=<YOUR_IP_OR_DOMAIN>`

   `HTTPS=true`

   `PORT=443`

   `SSL_CRT_FILE=.cert/your_domain.crt`

   `SSL_KEY_FILE=.cert/your_domain.key`

Note: In my case I did not use the 443 port because I'm using port forwarding, so I can use any port inside my internal network. Also the IP address you can use the public one directly or you can forward to any private address (this is what I do).

Comment: Did you mean: 

SSL_CRT_FILE=.cert/your_domain.crt

SSL_KEY_FILE=.cert/your_domain.key

Comment: Exactly. Thanks for the catch. I'm updating now.

Comment: Someone might want to use self signed certs for their development environment though

Comment: You can use the same method with self-signed certs, you just need to do an extra step and trust them in your browser when you hit the page.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did:

```
bash <(wget -qO- https://gist.github.com/w35l3y/5bb7fe8508d576472136f35428019177/raw/local-cert-generator.sh)
```

Then I double clicked and imported: `rootCA.pem` and `server.pem`

Then I modified `package.json`:

```
"start": "HTTPS=true react-scripts start",
"prestart": "cp -f /path/to/server.pem ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/ssl",
```

Very important sources:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/226386/wget-a-script-and-run-it
- https://gist.github.com/w35l3y/5bb7fe8508d576472136f35428019177

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: Is the certificate not self-signed?

Comment: I explained a way to copy a certificate to the right folder, as he already have the certificate.
The bash command is just an example to generate the certificate.
His question is "How can I use my own SSL certificate" and I explained how... copying the certificate to that folder.

Answer (score 1):

**Simplest way is to run reactjs with SSL on Ubuntu and windows is -**

Create **cert.pem** and **key.pem** file and put it in ssl folder in app root folder

add below lines in scripts of package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "...",
    "build": "...",
    "ssl-linux": "export HTTPS=true&&SSL_CRT_FILE=/ssl/cert.pem&&SSL_KEY_FILE=/ssl/key.pem craco start",
    "ssl-win": "set HTTPS=true&&npm start"
  },
```

**Ubuntu - npm run ssl-linux on ubuntu**

**Windows - npm run ssl-win**

To create pem file on ubuntu

```
Step 1.  openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout keytmp.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
Step 2.  openssl rsa -in keytmp.pem -out key.pem
```

Sample folder structure

[image]

Comment: Why all these steps for a self-signed certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Use [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert) to create the self-signed cert and install it. I tried other methods but they're error prone.

Example using macOS:

```
brew install mkcert
mkcert -install
mkcert localhost
```

Edit package.json:

```
"start": "HTTPS=true SSL_CRT_FILE=localhost.pem SSL_KEY_FILE=localhost-key.pem react-scripts start",
```

Comment: Why all these steps for a self-signed certificate? Why not just adding https=true in .env?

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a detailed answer since certificate errors tend to be very vague. I use IIS's Application Request Routing and url rewrite to manage it all.**

---

Okay first, my backend is Node.js app uses this same certificate, so I created a symlink between devserver/_certs and devclient/_certs, but the front-end and back-end want different files

Here's the relevant NodeJS code

```
const app = express()
...

const serverProcess = https.createServer(getSSLFiles(), app);
serverProcess.listen(11001, () => {
    console.log(`Server online.`)
});

function getSSLFiles() {
    return {
        // Note these two files used
        cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "..", "_certs", "fullchain.pem")), 
        key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "..", "_certs", "privkey.pem")),
    }
}

// This is unnecessary for the demonstration, just a nice function to always makre sure 
setInterval(function () {
    serverProcess.setSecureContext(getSSLFiles())
}, 86400000); // 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000, once a day
```

And then I use this env file, literally named `.env`, again with the symlink noded above. Some answers on the web say to use **SSL_CERT_FILE**, but it's **SSL_CRT_FILE** (no E in CRT)

```
# Whatever port you want
PORT="11002"
HOST="mydevsite.local"
HTTPS="true"
SSL_CRT_FILE="./_certs/cert.crt"
SSL_KEY_FILE="./_certs/privkey.pem"
```

with this command, (`npm run dev`)

```
"dev": "env-cmd -f .env react-scripts start",
```

And then finally my web.config file that takes advantage of of both of these. There are two api rewrite rules, one is disabled. Choose whichever style you like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="well-known">
                    <match url="^\.well-known/acme-challenge/([\w-]+)$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/.well-known/acme-challenge/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="api-https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <!-- Note that this rewrites
                    https://mydevsite.local/api/path/to/dest to https://mydevsite.local:11001/path/to/dest,
                    'api' is deliberately removed -->
                    <match url="api/(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^https://" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://mydevsite.local:11001/{R:1}" />
                    <!-- ^ 11001, my server port -->
                </rule>
                <rule name="api-https2" stopProcessing="true" enabled="false">
                    <!-- Note that this rewrites
                    https://mydevsite.local/api/path/to/dest to https://mydevsite.local:11001/api/path/to/dest -->
                    <match url="api/.*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^https://" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://mydevsite.local:11001/{R:0}" />
                    <!-- ^ 11001, my server port -->
                </rule>
                <rule name="ReverseProxy" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://mydevsite.local:11002/{R:1}" />
                    <!-- ^ 11002, my client port -->
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```