# 'HTTPS' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: npm, windows-10, command-prompt, yarnpkg, umijs

I want to run a React project in my Windows (as a virtual machine of my Mac).

In a Command Prompt, after running `yarn` to install dependencies. I did `yarn start`. And it gave me `'HTTPS' is not recognized as an internal or external command` error.

```
> yarn start
yarn run v1.13.0
$ HTTPS=true CERT=cert/localhost.crt KEY=cert/localhost.key umi dev
'HTTPS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**Edit 1**:

I upgraded node to `v12.16.1` (`yarn` to `1.13.0`, npm to `6.13.4`), and did `yarn add https` and `yarn add https-localhost`. However, `yarn start` still returned `'HTTPS' is not recognized as an internal or external command`.

`umi dev` returned `'umi' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`:

```
>umi dev
'umi' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: you need https package. Install it locally or globally.

Comment: Do you mean `SSL Certificate`?

Comment: no. i mean npm package

Comment: check this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/https-localhost

Comment: I think it's because of your node version. From a version later, https became a build-in module on node. What is your node version?

Comment: node version is `10.15.0`

Comment: I tried `yarn add https-localhost` and added the message to OP. After that, `yarn start` still returned the https error.

Comment: Please see my OP, it still did not work...

Comment: `$ HTTPS=true CERT=cert/localhost.crt KEY=cert/localhost.key umi dev` - That looks like a shell command (Bourne/bash/Unix/Linux/POSIX) that invokes the command `umi dev` after setting variables `HTTPS`, `CERT`, and `KEY`. I'm not familiar with React or Yarn, but could it be it doesn't support Windows, or that something is misconfigured to make it think it's on a Unix-like system?

Comment: Make sure you have the following lines in .env file:
`HTTPS=true`
`PORT=8080`
`HOST=localhost`

Comment: You don't need to install any package neither.

Comment: Check also my answer about valid certificate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192491/how-can-i-provide-a-ssl-certificate-with-create-react-app/72613085#72613085

Answer (score 9):

Just add the following lines to `.env`:

`HTTPS=true`

`PORT=8080`

`HOST=localhost`

If you want to use another host or port, feel free to replace localhost with the IP address you want and the port with any available port number. If you don't have `.env` file, just create it in your react root folder.

After this you can run `yarn start` or `npm start` and your project will use https instead of `http`.

If you need to use a real certificate inatead of a self-signed, then you can take a look at may answer here: [How can I provide a SSL certificate with create-react-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192491/how-can-i-provide-a-ssl-certificate-with-create-react-app/72613085#72613085)

Comment: If you need to use a real certificate inatead of a self-signed, the you can take a look at may answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192491/how-can-i-provide-a-ssl-certificate-with-create-react-app/72613085#72613085

Answer (score 5):

On windows you need to include 'set' as in "set HTTPS=true" to set an environment variable.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered a similar issue running in a Windows environment, the solution was to include '&&' after setting the environment variables and the command that follows.

Example:

```
set HTTPS=true set CERT=.cert/localhost.crt set KEY=.cert/localhost.key && umi dev
```

React Example:

```
set HTTPS=true set SSL_CRT_FILE=.certificates/localhost.crt set SSL_KEY_FILE=.certificates/localhost.key && react-scripts start
```

Answer (score 1):

For time being

Instead of:
"start": "CERT=cert/localhost.crt KEY=cert/localhost.key umi dev react-scripts start",

Do this only:
"start": "react-scripts start",

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem on Windows but instead of "Command Prompt" I use [Git Bash](https://git-scm.com/downloads).
So if you like Git Bash, this answer might be helpful to you.

1. Step One: Leave your package.json in its original form, we're going to add the environment variables in the next steps:

   [image: package.json]

---

2. Step Two: Create a file that will set the environment variables:

   [image]

---

3. Step Three: Add your environment variables to that file. `set` didn't work for me but `export` did:

   [image]

> Note: The default port is 3000, so if you're not exporting a PORT in this file, React will start at 'https://localhost:3000'

---

4. Step Four: `source` the file. You basically have 2 options:

   - Option 1: In order to use these variables for the current session only:
     [image]
   - Option 2: In order to use these variables for any session, add these lines to your `~/.bashrc` file:
     [image]

---

5. Step Five: Run `npm start` or `yarn start` and you should be using https on localhost:

   [image]

> Note: I'm not exporting a PORT here, just using the default port 3000.

Answer (score 1):

I just remove
"start": "HTTPS=true react-scripts start",
to
"start": "react-scripts start",
in file package.json

Answer (score 0):

Just by adding `HTTPS=true` is enough to make it work.

You can add more to the .env file like the `PORT` if the post is other than 3000.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add `set` before the `HTTPS=true`. Also, add `&&` after the first command finishes and the `react-scripts` command starts. This will ensure the proper execution of your command.

The below example worked when I tested it:

```
set HTTPS=true SSL_CRT_FILE=./certs/cert.crt SSL_KEY_FILE=./certs/cert.key && react-scripts start
```