# How to fix "net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID" when sending a request to an https:// API?

Tags: reactjs, http, https

I have a React application (create-react-app) running on http://localhost:3000/ and I need to send a request to an API (Java with Spring Boot) that is available on "https://review-feature-...api/partner".

However, when I send the request, I get the following error on my Chrome console:

```
POST https://review-feature-...api/partner net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

I've tried to change my React application to run on https://localhost:3000, but it doesn't work because I have a Keycloak authorization server running behind my React app, so I have to find a way to send the request using http://localhost:3000/ anyway.

I've also tried to use the following environment variables ([How can I provide a SSL certificate with create-react-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192491/how-can-i-provide-a-ssl-certificate-with-create-react-app)) but it doens't work.

```
SSL_CRT_FILE=.cert/server.crt
SSL_KEY_FILE=.cert/server.key
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue with my project. Please let me know if you found any solution.