# Adding identity server authentication to .NET Core 3 app fails with 'Key type not specified.'

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to add identity server authentication to a .NET Core 3 API project.

I've added this code

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    … 

    var identityBuilder = services.AddIdentityServer();

    identityBuilder.AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, DbContext>();

    services
        .AddAuthentication()
        .AddIdentityServerJwt();

    var fileName = Path.Combine("Certificates", "certificatefile.pfx");
    var cert = new X509Certificate2(fileName, "veryDifficultPassword");
    identityBuilder.AddSigningCredential(cert);

    … 
}
```

And:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    … 
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseIdentityServer(); // <--- this line throws error.
    app.UseAuthorization();
    … 
}
```

There is a file which is read and loaded properly in the `/Certificates` folder—I can inspect the `cert` variable and it looks correct.

Everything I have tried so far ends with the line `app.UseIdentityServer();` blowing up with:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Key type not specified.'

Any suggestions?

**Update: Including stacktrace**

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Key type not specified.
  Source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureSigningCredentials.LoadKey()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureSigningCredentials.Configure(ApiAuthorizationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Get>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.Get(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServerBuilderConfigurationExtensions.<>c.<AddClients>b__7_1(IServiceProvider sp)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IdentityServerApplicationBuilderExtensions.TestService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type service, ILogger logger, String message, Boolean doThrow)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IdentityServerApplicationBuilderExtensions.Validate(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IdentityServerApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityServer(IApplicationBuilder app, IdentityServerMiddlewareOptions options)
   at Boskapstorget.API.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in C:\Private\Kod\Boskapstorget\Backend\src\Boskapstorget.API\Startup.cs:line 86
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<UseStartup>b__2(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.<StartAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56094788/identityserver4-not-working-in-production

Comment: I read through that before posting this, it does seem similar, however the answer does not seem to apply to asp.net core (I tried to no avail).

Comment: ``app.UseAuthentication();`` is not required. Remove it and check. It will add it by default with ``UseIdentityServer();``

Comment: I removed it, still same error. interesting thing about that is that in the angular template app its like that from the start too.

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace of the exception? I have just tried this with the template created using `dotnet new react -o reacttest -au Individual`.  I then generated a pfx file by exporting a certificate from my certificate store and added the lines of code shown in your question.  I can run the application with no exceptions.   Perhaps your pfx file is not correct?

Comment: @Richard I've included the stacktrace. The template works for me as well. But I want to incorporate this in an existing app. I have copied all the code pertaining to this from the template, but I must be missing something as it throws this error every time I try to run it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't think that the code you have added to install a signing certificate has caused the problem. The code in the stacktrace is being executed because `identityBuilder.AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, DbContext>();` calls `AddSigningCredentials()` which eventually configures code to look in appsettings.json for key definition `Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureSigningCredentials`:

```
public SigningCredentials LoadKey()
{
    var key = new KeyDefinition();
    _configuration.Bind(key);
    switch (key.Type)
    {
        case KeySources.Development:
            var developmentKeyPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), key.FilePath ?? DefaultTempKeyRelativePath);
            var createIfMissing = key.Persisted ?? true;
            _logger.LogInformation($"Loading development key at '{developmentKeyPath}'.");
            var developmentKey = new RsaSecurityKey(SigningKeysLoader.LoadDevelopment(developmentKeyPath, createIfMissing))
            {
                KeyId = "Development"
            };
            return new SigningCredentials(developmentKey, "RS256");
        case KeySources.File:
            var pfxPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), key.FilePath);
            var pfxPassword = key.Password;
            var storageFlags = GetStorageFlags(key);
            _logger.LogInformation($"Loading certificate file at '{pfxPath}' with storage flags '{key.StorageFlags}'.");
            return new SigningCredentials(new X509SecurityKey(SigningKeysLoader.LoadFromFile(pfxPath, key.Password, storageFlags)), "RS256");
        case KeySources.Store:
            if (!Enum.TryParse<StoreLocation>(key.StoreLocation, out var storeLocation))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Invalid certificate store location '{key.StoreLocation}'.");
            }
            _logger.LogInformation($"Loading certificate with subject '{key.Name}' in '{key.StoreLocation}\\{key.StoreName}'.");
            return new SigningCredentials(new X509SecurityKey(SigningKeysLoader.LoadFromStoreCert(key.Name, key.StoreName, storeLocation, GetCurrentTime())), "RS256");
        case null:
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Key type not specified.");
        default:
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Invalid key type '{key.Type ?? "(null)"}'.");
    }
}
```

You are hitting the `null` case because your *appsettings.json* or *appsettings.Development.json* file does not configure the `Key`.

I can reproduce your problem in 2 ways:

Commenting out the key configuration in *appsetting.**Development**.json*

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "IdentityServer": {
    //"Key": {
    //  "Type": "Development"
    //}
  }
}
```

This assumes you are running\debugging in Development environment

[image]

The second way to reproduce is to configure to run in Production which doesn't have a `Key` definition by default in *appsettings.json*

[image]

I think the solution to your problem would be to define the certificate file in *appsettings.json* or *appsettings.Development.json*:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
      "Type": "File",
      "FilePath": "Certificates\\certificatefile.pfx",
      "Password": "veryDifficultPassword"
    }
  }
}
```

and remove this code

```
var fileName = Path.Combine("Certificates", "certificatefile.pfx");
var cert = new X509Certificate2(fileName, "veryDifficultPassword");
identityBuilder.AddSigningCredential(cert);
```

Comment: This solved it. Thank you very much for the time and effort you put into this.

Comment: My problem was exactly as you stated, an error in the appsettings file.

Comment: Hi I put the certificate in App_Data

then
"Key": {
      "Type": "File",
      "FilePath": "App_Data\\my.pfx",
      "Password": "TTYYAYYAA"
    }

And I still get Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: The system cannot find the file specified.\r\n 

I'm on a shared host

(on my computer it works fine)