# identity server with plesk: Couldn't find a valid certificate with subject 'CN=SigningCertificate'

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, identityserver4, plesk, asp.net-core-3.0

Im working with a web hosting server and they have a plesk interface. I'm getting an error when I try to deploy my asp net core api with angular.

Actually it is a basic net core 3.0 template with angular and it uses identity server. Without changing anything if I upload to the server it doesn't work I have certificate issue:

ERROR:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Couldn't find a valid certificate with subject 'CN=SigningCertificate' on the 'LocalMachine\My'
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.SigningKeysLoader.LoadFromStoreCert(String subject, String storeName, StoreLocation storeLocation, DateTimeOffset currentTime)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureSigningCredentials.LoadKey()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureSigningCredentials.Configure(ApiAuthorizationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Get>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.Get(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServerBuilderConfigurationExtensions.<>c.<AddClients>b__7_1(IServiceProvider sp)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IdentityServerApplicationBuilderExtensions.TestService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type service, ILogger logger, String message, Boolean doThrow)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IdentityServerApplicationBuilderExtensions.Validate(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IdentityServerApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityServer(IApplicationBuilder app, IdentityServerMiddlewareOptions options)
   at COZ.Web.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) in D:\GIT_HUB\web-vpswimschool\Code\COZ.Web\COZ.Web\Startup.cs:line 136
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.BuildApplication()
2019-09-29 08:19:53.259 -04:00 [WRN] Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage.
2019-09-29 08:19:53.259 -04:00 [WRN] Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits.
2019-09-29 08:19:53.272 -04:00 [WRN] No XML encryptor configured. Key "45t45-345g-456g-456g-asdfsc234fdw2" may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
```

Code:

```
var idpBuilder = services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Solution 1 not worked. I tried to create an certificate with openssl and use it:

```
                var fileName = "cert.pfx";
                if (!File.Exists(fileName))
                {
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("Signing Certificate is missing!");
                }
                var cert = new X509Certificate2(fileName, "pass");
                idpBuilder.AddSigningCredential(cert);
```

Solution 2 not worked. I tried to use an existing certificate in the server so I listed all certificate and used one existing:

```
using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
                {
                    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                    X509Certificate2Collection col = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "A23JDHR87374HDZERJH", false);
                    var cert = col[0];
                    idpBuilder.AddSigningCredential(cert);
                }
```

Anybody can help?

Thank you

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58135672/adding-identityserver-authentication-to-net-core-3-app-fails-with-key-type-not

Answer (score 3):

Seems similar to my answer I wrote here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66448397/3850405

I finally solved it like this:

Created a new certificate in Powershell as Administrator:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "blazortest" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\CurrentUser\My"
```

appsettings.json:

```
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "BlazorTest.Client": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      }
    },
    "Key": {
      "Type": "Store",
      "StoreName": "My",
      "StoreLocation": "CurrentUser",
      "Name": "CN=blazortest"
    }
  },
```

Remove below if you want to test this locally from `appsettings.Development.json`

```
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
      "Type": "Development"
    }
  }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.0#example-deploy-to-azure-app-service

This worked locally. I then used `mmc.exe` to export the certificate as a `.pfx` file and uploaded it via `Azure App Service` -> `TLS/SSL settings`.

[image]

I then used `Azure Cloud Shell` to enable access to the certificate like this:

```
az webapp config appsettings set --name <app-name> --resource-group <resource-group-name> --settings WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES=<comma-separated-certificate-thumbprints>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code#load-the-certificate-in-code

You can also add the `Certificate Thumbprint` manually by adding `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` to `Configuration`:

[image]

Then it finally worked!

If you get an error from Azure Cloud Shell like:

> ResourceGroupNotFound: Resource group '' could not be found.

Make sure you are in the right subscription and set the correct subscription with these commands:

```
az account show

az account list

az account set --subscription <subscriptionId>
```

If you host on `IIS` you need to import the `.pfx` certificate to the `Personal` folder for `Local Computer` and then select `Manage Private Keys...` and give access to the user running the `Application Pool`.

[image]