# Azure static web app Blazor WASM .Net Core API and Identity - Could not load settings from '_configuration

Tags: asp.net-core, identity, blazor-webassembly, azure-static-web-app

I want to publish my VS solution to Azure static web app, I'm using the template that has Blazor WASM, a .Net Core API and Authentication with Identity inside the API.

It works fine on my local machine but after being published as an Azure static web app, it runs but remains authorizing...

The error is:

> Could not load settings from '_configuration'

This is the browser console:

[image]

Client - program.cs:

```
public class Program
{
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

            builder.Services.AddHttpClient("x.ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
                .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

            // Supply HttpClient instances that include access tokens when making requests to the server project
            builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("x.ServerAPI"));

            builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }
}
```

Need help making this work...

Comment: Hi, I have been struggling with the exact same problem for the past week now myself. I have even tried adding a .pfx copy of my certificate in the wwwroot and include the pfx key in the appsettings.json file

Comment: @Kommando1980 I have found the solution to the problem already, just follow the link bellow.

Comment: Thank you for the message. I am still not getting this to work. Not sure what to try next :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was happening was the lack of a certificate in my case, I followed this answear and it worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66448397/12824729

I dont know if it is possible to work without a certificate when we have to do authentications, tried making the Key type development but wont authenticate..

Comment: Hi, I do have a pfx and specified the key which works fine locally, but not after hosting to my domain provider?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67425353/authenticationservice-js1-get-https-mydomainname-co-za-configuration-project

Comment: Your certificate CN name must coincide with your domain and the store should be currentuser/my instead localmachine

Comment: Hi, it is the same certificate - i obtained it from my service provider and they confirmed it is the same ssl that was converted to pfx. it is the same one used on the domain

Comment: Hi, in my case the problem was resolved by my hosting provider. They advised that the application pool must be granted full access to the root folder (the folder in which wwwroot folder exists). After doing this my website is now working.