# AuthenticationService.js:1 GET https://MYDOMAINNAME.co.za/_configuration/ProjectTest.Client 404

Tags: authentication, blazor, webassembly, hosted

I have created a simple **Blazor wasm hosted web application**, using .net 5.0
**I enabled authentication - using the default .sqlite database.**
This all works fine when debugging the application locally.

However, when I try and host the published server project I get this error:

AuthenticationService.js:1 GET https://MYDOMAINNAME.co.za/_configuration/ProjectTest.Client 404

**Hosted on my domain with ssl (pfx) certificate in place:**

[image]

**Locally**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "ProjectTest.Client": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      }
    },
    "Key": {
      "Type": "File",
      "FilePath": "cert.pfx",
      "Password": "password"
    }

Comment: i tried to add the pfx file and password, this works locally but does not seem to help when publishing the site.

Comment: Have you found something? I have a similar error, but it doesn't work locally.... (since I had add Authentication)

Comment: Hi, yes I solved this issue by allowing the account under which the IIS application pool runs full access to the folder in which the web app is hosted. now it is working locally and when hosted (my issue was on the hosting side, but a friendly administrator figured this out for me)