# Blazor WebAssembly App with Individual Accounts and ASP.NET Core Hosted - Object reference not set to an instance of an object - AddSigningCredentials

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, identityserver4

Creating a new `Blazor WebAssembly App` with `Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.11.3` with these specifications: `Target Framework .NET 5.0`, `Authentication Type Individual Accounts` and `ASP.NET Core Hosted`:

[image]

I then only edited `appsettings.Development.json` and removed the following:

```
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
      "Type": "Development"
    }
  }
```

This gives the exception:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
> object.
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServerBuilderConfigurationExtensions+<>c.<AddSigningCredentials>b__10_2(IServiceProvider
> sp)

In `Startup.cs` I then tried to add `AddDeveloperSigningCredential` like this:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
```

However this gives me the same error. I then tried `.AddDeveloperSigningCredential(true);`, same error.

I then tried modified code from Microsoft Docs:

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = null;
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Test\test.pfx");
certificate = new X509Certificate2(bytes, "SuperSecurePassword123!@");

services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options => { })
    .AddSigningCredential(certificate);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-identity-server?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#host-in-azure-app-service-with-certificate-token-signing

Same error.

I then tried getting certificate from Store:

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = null;
using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
{
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    X509Certificate2Collection certificates = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "MyThumbprint", false);

    if (certificates.Count > 0)
        certificate = certificates[0];
}

services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options => { })
    .AddSigningCredential(certificate);
```

Same error even though I have verified that an actual certificate is picked up in both cases:

[image]

I then tried removing every configuration with `IdentityServer` from `appsettings.json`

```
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "BlazorTestWithIdentityServer.Client": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      }
    }
  },
```

And replaced it with this:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.Clients.AddIdentityServerSPA("BlazorTestWithIdentityServer.Client", builder =>
        {
            builder.WithRedirectUri("/authentication/login-callback");
            builder.WithLogoutRedirectUri("/authentication/logout-callback");
        });
    })
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
```

Still causing the same error.

Running the code below:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.Clients.AddIdentityServerSPA("BlazorTestWithIdentityServer.Client", builder =>
        {
            builder.WithRedirectUri("/authentication/login-callback");
            builder.WithLogoutRedirectUri("/authentication/logout-callback");
        });
    });
```

With `appsettings.Development.json`:

```
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
      "Type": "Development"
    }
  }
```

Everything works as expected.

How can I get `AddDeveloperSigningCredential` and `AddSigningCredential` to work with `services.AddIdentityServer()`?