# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer Error when deploying Asp.Net Core with React.js template (dotnet SDK v7.0.101) to Azure Web App

Tags: reactjs, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-identity

I have tried to deploy Asp.Net Core with React.js template (dotnet SDK v7.0.101) to a new Azure Web App with 'Individual Accounts' authentication type.

The application functions properly when using localhost but not after being deployed. I'm getting the following error:

```
[Error] 

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler:
 Exception occurred while processing message.System.NullReferenceException: 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.
IdentityServerJwtBearerOptionsConfiguration.ResolveAuthorityAndKeysAsync(MessageReceivedContext messageReceivedContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
```

I suspect its a problem with IdentityServer settings in appsettings.json:

```
    "IdentityServer": {
        "Clients": {
             "AspNetCoreWithReactjs": {
                "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
              }
            }
         },
```

When I deploy using *appsettings.Development.json* IdentityServer settings, the page loads but login doesn't work.

I'm hoping ***someone with knowledge of Asp.Net IdentiyServer*** can advise me what I need to do either in appsettings.json, program.cs or elsewhere to resolve this bug.

Besides the connection string nothing has been altered in the provided template so I'm not sure why it doesn't successfully deploy.

**Expected outcome:**

I was expecting the page to load and work in the same way as it does when running via localhost.

---

**Steps to reproduce:**

**New Project**

- Create a new project in Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition
- Use the *Asp.Net Core With React.js* template

**Configure your new project:**

- Project name: AspNetCoreWithReactjs
- Location: C:\Users...\source\repos
- Solution: Create new solution
- Solution name: AspNetCoreWithReactjs
- Place solution and project in the same directory: false

**Additional information:**

- Framework: .NET 7.0 (Standard Term Support)
- Authentication type: Individual Accounts
- Do not use top-level statements: false

**Appsettings.json Connection String**

- Changed DefaultConnection connection string to use my existing Azure Sql database
- Successfully ran ‘update-database’ in Package Manager Console

**Publish Profile**

- Target: Azure
- Specific target: Azure App Service (Windows)
- Name: AspNetCoreWithReactjs2023010123926
- Hosting Plan: Central US, S1

**Publish:**

- Configuration: Release
- Target Framework: net7.0
- Deployment Mode: Framework-dependent
- Target Runtime: Portable

**After publishing, the url loads with a 500 server error:**

- Browser log message: Failed to load resource: the server responed with a status of 500 ()
- Request URL: https:// AspNetCoreWithReactjs2023010123926.azurewebsites.net/
- Request Method: GET
- Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
- Local Storage: null (no local storage objects)
- Cookies: ARRAffinitySameSite, ARRAffinity

**Details from Azure logs:**

```
Connecting...
2023-01-01T12:58:30  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service. The default timeout is 2 hours. Change the timeout with the App Setting SCM_LOGSTREAM_TIMEOUT (in seconds).
2023-01-01 12:58:36.131 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler: Exception occurred while processing message.System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.IdentityServerJwtBearerOptionsConfiguration.ResolveAuthorityAndKeysAsync(MessageReceivedContext messageReceivedContext)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
2023-01-01 12:58:36.150 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer: Connection ID "17582052946865029492", Request ID "80000176-0000-f400-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.IdentityServerJwtBearerOptionsConfiguration.ResolveAuthorityAndKeysAsync(MessageReceivedContext messageReceivedContext)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.0
#Fields: date time s-sitename cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Cookie) cs(Referer) cs-host sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken
2023-01-01 12:57:59 ASPNETCOREWITHREACTJS20230101233926 GET / X-ARR-LOG-ID=392d3d5f-4c6c-47ff-b6a1-c99b689a7fb2 443 - 120.148.130.43 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/108.0.0.0+Safari/537.36+Edg/108.0.1462.54 ARRAffinity=146b48f2ff5efabcc69048783c5815d34c57b6d7adedb21b164d0e292cee67ef;+ARRAffinitySameSite=146b48f2ff5efabcc69048783c5815d34c57b6d7adedb21b164d0e292cee67ef https://portal.azure.com/ aspnetcorewithreactjs20230101233926.azurewebsites.net 500 0 0 366 1700 5379
2023-01-01 12:57:59 ~1ASPNETCOREWITHREACTJS20230101233926 GET /api/logstream/ X-ARR-LOG-ID=058aae75-bbeb-442b-adf5-7585174fab8b 443 - 120.148.130.43 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/108.0.0.0+Safari/537.36+Edg/108.0.1462.54 - - aspnetcorewithreactjs20230101233926.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 64 672 1603 35233
```

**Screenshots:**

[Step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcjFF.png)

[Step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ws7bl.png)

[Step3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCerS.png)

[Step7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw7rq.png)

[Step9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGOLb.png)

[Step10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZVVr.png)

[ErrorImage3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qIcy.png)

**IdentityServerJwtBearerOptionsConfiguration**

I found the offending class on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer/src/Authentication/IdentityServerJwtBearerOptionsConfiguration.cs

Is it possible to 'scaffold' libaries that are imported as DLLs so I can stick a breakpoint in it? I know this would only work for the development version but still might provide some insights.

C# is a great language to code in but its way more difficult than eg Node.js to debug errors related to 3rd party libraries.

I should probably just move on to a Duende sample but this default template bug has me triggered.

Comment: Please [find Web App down in  your azure portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQZs8.png), and get more details.  You can find it by navigating to `Diagnose and solve problems` -> `Web App Down`.

Comment: @JasonPan WebAppDown not reporting anything: [WebAppDown](https://i.imgur.com/zxhAVSL.png).

Comment: If anyone wants to reproduce on their own setup to investigate, it takes about 20 minutes to complete. See my 'Steps To Reproduce'.

Comment: It seems not to be a problem with your code, but with the settings, indeed. Mind that the main differences between a published application (not just in .NET, but in other frameworks this is something trivial) and its development version usually is: 1) the environment itself (local machine vs server) and 2) the build type (Development vs Release, for instance). In your case, I would start looking if there are differences between your appsettings.Development.json (which, in an ASP.NET project, is used by default in your local environment) and your appsettings.json (published version).

Comment: Please check if the time range is correct? Or you can log in the kudu site, try to find more error details.

Comment: @JasonPan Error details have been supplied. You can reproduce the error by following my 'Steps to Reproduce'.

Comment: @JsonPan I've been down a huge number of different paths to debug. Each leads to rambling vague documentation about auth. In my opinion only a specialist who has studied this in depth can resolve it. Time and energy I'd rather spend learning React or C#. I suspect the template has been left in an incomplete state for reasons related to Microsoft politics e.g., to divert people into using Blazor etc. Thanks for having a look though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read Microsofts post for `IdentityServer` *Host in Azure App Service with a custom domain and certificate*? Given that `IdentityServerJwtBearerOptionsConfiguration.ResolveAuthorityAndKeysAsync` fails I think it is related to this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-identity-server?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#host-in-azure-app-service-with-a-custom-domain-and-certificate

Written for `Blazor WebAssembly` but Identity Server areas are still the same.

I have written an answer how to solve it here as well:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66448397/3850405

Comment: Thanks @Ogglas. I followed all the steps from your learn.microsoft link except the ones related to custom domain but unfortunately got the exact same error. I'll try again later with one of my spare custom domains and see if that helps. I'm pessimistic due to the '..not set to an instance of an object' message in the error indicating something hasn't been instantiated rather than setting not found. So possibly a library version mismatch which is baffling because all the code should be coming from my repo. tbc..

Comment: Actually its like there's an actual bug in JwtBearerHandler class that only surfaces in prod deployments.

Comment: @severalpens Have you tried using a certificate on localhost IIS? Try using my guide and run the app on IIS and not Visual Studio IIS Express. Then you can see if it is Azure related or something else. You can also remove `"IdentityServer:Key:Type": "Development"` from `appsettings.Development.json`  to verify that it is not related to Identity Server token signing in production.