# Providing IdentityServer4 with a key on Linux App Service

Tags: c#, azure, identityserver4, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to configure IdentityServer4 on a netcore 3.1 app running on a Linux App Service (B1). I'm attempting to load the key from the file system and pass it to IdentityServer at Configuration time ([as per here](https://benjii.me/2017/06/creating-self-signed-certificate-identity-server-azure/)), but the key I provide seems to be getting thrown away as IdentityServer tries to look for config to find key itself ([line 70 appears to be where the exception is thrown from](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/master/src/ApiAuth.IS/Configuration/ConfigureSigningCredentials.cs)).

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddSigningCredential(GetCert())
            .AddApiAuthorization<IdentityUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseIdentityServer(); // exception thrown here 
        app.UseAuthorization();
    }


    private X509Certificate2 GetCert()
    {
        // Linux App Service puts keys configured in the App Service in this directory
        // I have checked - the key is correctly placed here
        var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("/var/ssl/private/XYZTHUMBPRINTXYZ.p12");
        return new X509Certificate2(bytes);
    }
```

I should note this isn't actually an issue getting the key onto Azure, or onto the App itself, I've verified its on the file system and the app can create a valid key from it, it just seems to be discarded by IdentityServer.

Because the Window's type KeyStore is not available on the Linux Service, the appsettings config (example below) doesn't work.

```
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
      "Type": "Store",
      "StoreName": "My",
      "StoreLocation": "CurrentUser",
      "Name": "CN=example.com"
    }   
  },
```

Comment: If the private key is protected in that file then you'll need to provide the passphrase to allow the library to decrypt it. I suspect if you don't provide that then it will only load the public key and other metadata.

Comment: @mackie nothing to to with the key it turns out - have answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gotten to the bottom of it with help from the answer this question - [Adding Identityserver authentication to net core 3 app fails with 'Key type not specified.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58135672/adding-identityserver-authentication-to-net-core-3-app-fails-with-key-type-not)

The problem is that `AddApiAuthorization<IdentityUser, ApplicationDbContext>()` internally makes a call to `AddSigningCredentials()` which will instruct IdentityServer to look in app config to find out what keys to use. It will do this whether the `AddSigningCredential(cert)` is called before or after.

To solve my issue, I inlined the `AddApiAuthorization<IdentityUser, ApplicationDbContext>()` method and removed the line that looked for more keys from config, and the app now works on the linux appservice.

I also asked the question on IdentityServer's github, leaving the link in case the project owners comment on the resolution - https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/4000

Comment: Identity server guys just answered that it is not their problem but couldn't they provide a way to define a config for linux?

Comment: Also how did you navigate around inlining .ConfigureReplacedServices() as it is internal static method.

Comment: @MarkoPrcać I looked at the source code on github :)

Comment: basically any question to IS4 is not their problem. and their bot simply close unwanted topics with offer of a commercial support.. idk why MS offers this lousy solution out of the box.. i wish i knew beforehand